# App works locally, errors in Heroku. Is it because of my async = false tag?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, heroku

I took a template that was written with various plug ins and started to convert it to React. Converting the existing JavaScript files to work in React is beyond my ability, so what I did was:

```
componentDidMount(){
        var loadScripts = [
            './vendor/jquery/jquery.js',
            './vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js',
            './js/classie.js','./js/cbpAnimatedHeader.js',
            './vendor/jquery.easing/jquery.easing.min.js',
            './vendor/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.js',
            './vendor/magnific-popup/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js',
            './vendor/formstone/core.js',
            './vendor/formstone/transition.js',
            './vendor/formstone/background.js',
            './vendor/mixitup/jquery.mixitup.js',
            './vendor/wow/wow.min.js',
            './js/contact_me.js',
            './js/jqBootstrapValidation.js',
            './js/vitality.js'];

            loadScripts.forEach(function(src) {
                var script = document.createElement('script');
                script.src = src;
                script.async = false;
                document.head.appendChild(script);
            });
        }
```

and it works perfect locally. When I pushed to heroku, I am getting many errors. The errors lead me to believe the files are loading asynchronously. Does Heroku allow the async = false tag?

Here are the errors:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'scrollTop' of undefined
    at e (background.js:3)
    at HTMLDocument.c (background.js:3)
    at b (core.js:3)
    at Object.<anonymous> (core.js:3)
    at Object.<anonymous> (jquery.js:3366)
    at fire (jquery.js:3187)
    at Object.add [as done] (jquery.js:3246)
    at Array.<anonymous> (jquery.js:3365)
    at Function.each (jquery.js:365)
    at Object.<anonymous> (jquery.js:3361)
contact_me.js:3 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).jqBootstrapValidation is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (contact_me.js:3)
    at fire (jquery.js:3187)
    at Object.add [as done] (jquery.js:3246)
    at jQuery.fn.init.jQuery.fn.ready (jquery.js:3496)
    at jQuery.fn.init (jquery.js:2927)
    at jQuery (jquery.js:75)
    at contact_me.js:1
background.js:3 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'container' of undefined
    at jQuery.fn.init.g (background.js:3)
    at jQuery.fn.init.e (core.js:3)
    at jQuery.fn.init.i (core.js:3)
    at vitality.js:109
    at vitality.js:135
```

Comment: `and you can see all the errors in the console.log` how about you post the errors in the question, rather than force people to go to your site?

Comment: @JaromandaX I posted the errors. I originally listed the site because I thought maybe someone with more experience than I have would be able to see other  issues going on that I was not aware of.

Comment: you need to address `TypeError: $(...).jqBootstrapValidation is not a function` - seems like you have an issue with the order of scripts being loaded - as a guess, swap the order of `contact_me.js` and `jqBootstrapValidation.js` - as contact_me is relying on the `jqBootstrapValidation ` function

Comment: That is why I was asking if Heroku allows the tag async=false. The scripts are dynamically generated and locally it works fine because of the tag. I don't know why it is doing that in Heroku though.

Comment: async = false vs async = true wont make a difference ... you load contac_me before loading jqBootstrapValidation - but contact_me needs a function in jqBootstrapValidation ... try swapping the order, see if at least that one error is resolved

Comment: @JaromandaX Yes that fixed one of the errors. Thank you. Now that I know it is not what I originally thought I will see if I can figure the rest out. Do you know why it would always work locally however and not when on Heroku - or are there too many factors that could contribute to that question?

Comment: if it's the same code, and by locally you mean on a local http server (not using file:// ) then I can't see why there would be any difference at all